# Angular2 not working with Visual Studio 2015 Update

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying get started with Angular2 in VS 2015. I am following [this article](http://dotnetspeak.com/2016/06/setting-up-vs-2015-for-asp-net-core-rc2-and-angular-rc/comment-page-1).

But when running index.html file, its get stuck on '`Loading`...'.

Here are some configurations/code files being used.
Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "WebApplication8",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Startup.js file:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core',
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'router',
      'router-deprecated',
      'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

And index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="startup.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    Test
    <br />

    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Getting the following screenshots while debugging with Firebug:
[image]

[image]

Gulp.js file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('thirdparty', function () {
    gulp.src('./node_modules/core-js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/node_modules/core-js'));
    gulp.src('./node_modules/@angular/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/node_modules/@angular'));
    gulp.src('./node_modules/zone.js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/node_modules/zone.js'));
    gulp.src('./node_modules/systemjs/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/node_modules/systemjs'));
    gulp.src('./node_modules/reflect-metadata/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/node_modules/reflect-metadata'));
    gulp.src('./node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/node_modules/rxjs'));

});

gulp.task('copy', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.*', ['copy']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['thirdparty', 'copy', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Have you run npm install to install all Angular packages ? In addition have you copied the files to www folders ?

Comment: As mentioned in this article, I have installed 'npm install typings', and 'npm install gulp'... is there anything else I have to install ?

Comment: also before any thing, there issued command 'npm init'

Comment: yes, gulp do copy all files in wwwroot folder.

Comment: even the bundles folder?

Comment: Bundles folder even I could not see in node_modules/@angular/core

Comment: while not present in @angular/core folder, so not copied to wwwroot's same folder structure

Comment: what I have to do to get this bundles fodler...am I missing some 'npm install' ?

Comment: try only npm install and check in ur node modules whether u get the bundles folder in @angular/core

Comment: no, this command makes no difference. still no 'bundles' folder there.

Comment: Your startup.js file doesn't match that in the blog post you linked to. Have you tried copy and pasting that over yours to see if that works?
Also, can you show your gulp file so we can see what thats doing...

Comment: Yes also tried that startup.js file, just make changes to trying make it work. also added gulp file in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and tries, I found the solution, and I am posting it here, so that, it could help someone facing the similar problem.

Since I am using VS 2015 Update 3, TypeScript 1.8.35.0, npm version 3.10.6. 
After updating to get all these versions(before I was using an older version of npm, after reading some posts I found that it should be updated to latest version), then I make changes in `package.json` file. For example, changes the line `"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",` to `"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",`.

So my final `package.json` file becomes:

```
{
  "name": "WebApplication8",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Of-course, when you save the file, give Visual Studio some time to restore/install all dependencies.

And finally it works, just showing the message:

### My First Angular 2 App

Answer (score 1):

Try out this link, it has latest Angular 2 RC bits, ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM. There is GITHUB repo on that link

http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: thanks @Mithun, it helps me to find the right direction for solution.

Comment: Glad to hear that !!